# bootstrap radio buttons not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap doc's [example radio buttons code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/), but it does not display correctly:

[image: radio buttons wonky]

This is the code in the example:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>
```

See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwfsekzd/).

Any ideas on how to get these to work properly?

Comment: You point to the BS5 documentation but your example is using BS3. Fixing that solves the problem. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably **mistaken** the version of the `bootstrap` and you have linked it wrongly.

Here you have works example with `bootstrap@5`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">Radio 3</label>
</div>


    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I already noted this in a comment. No need to post it as an answer as it looks like you're just doing it for the rep.

Comment: I am trying to help and give the best answer I have at the given moment. I didn't see your comment at the time of replying.